# How to attach a tub and shower valve unit to wall framing

Tags: plumbing

I bought Glacier Bay tub & shower unit (3000 series). I'm not sure how to attach the mixer unit to the frame and also the shower and tub sprouts to the frame. The mixer unit has four holes, all threaded. Two for attaching the cover plate and two to attach a plastic plaster guard, with its own plastic screws. How to attach the unit to the wall (or wood frame)? Is the plaster guard needed?
[image]

Comment: What does the literature say?

Comment: The small book seem to suggest, the plaster guard should be used (its not very clear) Then There will be no holes to secure the mixed=r unit to the 2x4. Hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't normally attach a valve directly to framing. It sits in space and the various *pipes* connected to it are secured as appropriate. Same with the spout and shower nipple, both of which should be supported at their final bends. If using pex, consider transitioning to copper at a sensible point for each supply and the outputs.

You could add framing blocking to allow pipe straps near the valve if your studs happen to be so far away as to leave flex in the assembly. Do this *after* the plumbing is done so you can position it well and not have to work around it.

If you're still not satisfied with the rigidity this provides, you could run a block behind the valve and put a gob of silicone caulk in there as a mounting pad.

As long as you clamp each of the pipes at one point and allow movement between the clamp and the next bend you don't have to worry about expansion noise, etc. It's only when a straight run is pinched more than once that it becomes a problem. All framing penetrations should have adequate clearance.

The plaster guard is not necessarily critical if you're cutting a hole in a shower wall, but it would ensure clearance for mounting screws, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be attaching the vale body to the 2x4 between the studs. I was thinking not to attach the plaster guard, but use it as a guide to make the hole. In this case the extra screw holes will be used (where the plaster guard screws would go) to secure the mixer to the 2x4. Is this correct. Is there another way to attach it.

Comment: You're welcome. Please take the [tour] to learn how to follow up on your questions.

Comment: You're asking me how to do something I've never done before (mounting using screw holes not intended for mounting). I can't give advice on that, but I'm not sure how screw holes on the _front_ of the valve would work. There's not enough room for a lumber block there.

Comment: My question is how to secure the valve body to the 2x4? Some other brands have anchors with screw holes ( saw them in you tube).

Comment: The valve itself is not secured, but the four pipes form the valve are secured near the valve. I could use some silicone on the back of the valve and attach to a block of 2x4 between the studs, if needed. From Youtube I got the idea that the valve was supposed to be secured. Appreciate and thanks again @isherwood.